# OpenCV generalize vector product to return arbitrary sized Matrix

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to build a product operator that returns the product of two arbitrary sized vectors as a matrix.

For example the product `u = [u1; u2; u3]` with `v = [v1; v2; v3]` will be
`u*v' = [u1*v1 u1*v2 u1*v3; u2*v1 u2*v2 u2*v3; u3*v1 u3*v2 u3*v3]`.

How to generalize this for arbitrary sized Vecs using OpenCV with **`Matx`** and **`Vec`** Objects?

Comment: For future references, this operation is called `outer product`, a special case of `Kronecker product`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=matx#Matx), **`Matx`** is for small matrices whose type and size are known at compilation time.

For your case, you can both use [**`Mat`**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat) instead.

```
Mat u(n, 1, CV_32F);
Mat v(n, 1, CV_32F);
Mat res(n, n, CV_32F);

// compute here...
for (int i=0; i<res.rows; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<res.cols; j++)
    {
        res.at<float>(i, j) = u.at<float>(i, 0) * v.at<float>(j, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Using `Mat` you can do even better: if u and v are of type - say `Vec3f` - you just write `Mat res = Mat(u) * Mat(v).t()`. That's it. I was wondering if there is a possibility to do this using the `Matx` and `Vec` templates **without going through `Mat`**.